# javascript regular expression /e*/ results in empty match

Tags: javascript, regex

Why the javascript regular expression

```
/e*/
```

cannot match any part of the string "hello"?

I have already tried the following

```
"hello".match(/e*/)     //return [""]
```

while `/e+/` can match

```
"hello".match(/e+/)     //return ["e"]
```

Am I overlooking any simple stuff????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matched, or you would be getting `null` as a result.

The match is zero characters right at the beginning of the string. Your assertion is "find a place in the string where there is zero or more of `e`": Right at the start of the `hello`, there is zero or more of `e`, so we don't need to search further. `match` expectedly returns `[""]` (the zero characters matched).

On the other hand, `/e+/` wants *one* or more `e` characters; this is not satisfied at the start of the string, but it is satisfied at the very next position, and you get `["e"]`.